# touch .filename is not hiding the file

Tags: node.js, github, command-line

I'm trying to publish stuff on github and use the `touch.gitignore` to hide sensitive  stuff but `touch.filename` is not hiding any file on my windows 
and i'm using hyper terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`touch` by itself doesn't hide files.  What it does is create the file if it is missing and in any case, update its access and modification timestamps to now.

On Unix systems, files that begin with a dot are by default hidden from `ls` and most graphical interfaces simply by virtue of starting with a dot.  However, that isn't the case on Windows, which has its own hidden attribute.  Git Bash will hide the files in the standard Unix way when you use `ls` or any of the other Unix utilities, but Windows programs won't generally honor that and will require you to set the hidden flag if you don't want them to appear.